# How can I pass the output from stat to touch?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, sunos

I have a korn shell script on a server running SunOS 5.9 and I need to pass the output from `stat` to `touch` in order to reset the modified timestamp of a directory after doing something to it, e.g.

```
#Get modified timestamp of directory
mtime=$(stat -c %y  ${dirvar})

## Do something to directory that will alter its modified timestamp ##

#Reset modified timestamp of directory
touch -t "${mtime}" "${dirvar}"
```

How can I do this? The code above returns the error `touch: bad time specification`

I've tried this:

```
> stat -c %y ${dirvar} | awk '{ split($1, a, "-"); split($2, b, ":"); split(b[3], c, "."); print a[1]a[2]a[3]b[1]b[2]c[1]}'
```

Which takes this:

```
stat -c %y tmp
2018-12-19 11:28:41.000000000 +0000
```

And output it as this:

```
20181219112841
```

But I'm still getting the same `touch: bad time specification` error.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used `stat -t`, but the man page says:

```
   -t STAMP
          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

This means, you may want to try it using this format: `201812191128.41`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
mtime=$(stat -c %Y  ${dirvar})
touch -d "@${mtime}" "${dirvar}"
```

That uses the unix timestamp instead of an human readable date, but several linux utils accept that.

Comment: I tried this but am still getting the `touch: bad time specification` error.

Comment: @bad panda: I think I missed the sunos detail in you question. That works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want (at least on my Linux machine):

```
MTIME=$( stat now.txt | grep '^Modify:' | awk '{ print $2" "$3 }')
touch --date "$MTIME" now.txt
```

Alternatively, if you don't have access to the Linux touch (but do have GNU date) (operating on an `so` directory):

```
MTIME=$( stat so | grep '^Modify:' | awk '{ print $2" "$3 }')
TS=$( gdate --date "$MTIME" +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S )
touch -t $TS so
```

If you don't have access to GNU date, you will have to assemble the timestamp from the output of stat with something like:

```
mtime=$( stat so | grep '^Modify:' | awk '{ print $2" "$3 }')
yy=$( echo $mtime | cut -f1 -d- )
MM=$( echo $mtime | cut -f2 -d- )
DD=$( echo $mtime | cut -f3 -d- | cut -f1 -d\  )
hhmmss=$(echo $mtime | awk '{ print $2 }' )
hh=$( echo $hhmmss | cut -f1 -d: )
mm=$( echo $hhmmss | cut -f2 -d: )
ss=$( echo $hhmmss | cut -f3 -d: | cut -f1 -d. )

echo ${yy}${MM}${DD}
echo ${hh}${mm}.${ss}

ts=${yy}${MM}${DD}${hh}${mm}.${ss}
touch -t $ts so
```

Keep in mind that the act of setting the time changes the last changed time so you can't use this technique to cover your tracks if you modify a directory and hope to back date the directory to avoid detection.